# Why is AVSpeechSynthesizer reproducing more information that my text?

Tags: ios, swift, avspeechsynthesizer

I'm using `AVSpeechSynthesizer` for texts, here's relevant code.-

```
guard let nonNilText = text else { return }
let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: nonNilText)
utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: Locale.current.identifier)
utterance.rate = 0.4
synthesizer.speak(utterance)
```

Everything works fine, but seems that in some devices, particularly when the iPhone locale is set to English, voice over is reproducing what sounds like a description of the utterance itself: something like "Speak: rate xxx, voice name equals to com.apple..." before my text.

I'm guessing this might have to do with some accessibility setting, but can't figure out where to enable it to reproduce the issue on my iPhone. Any idea?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What finally worked was just removing the line.-

`utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: Locale.current.identifier)`

to let the synthesizer pick the voice itself.

Comment: But this honestly shouldn't be an issue though, I use ```Locale.preferredLanguages.first``` in an app of mine to detect user's set language of their phone and don't get any such voice over when I set ```utterance.voice``` to this.

Comment: Agree, I don't really understand where the issue was, because now it works on my device even with my original code, but my client kept complaining of the issue until I compiled without that line :/ Also, but I've read several sources complaining about issues with TTS on iOS16 but nothing compared with this.

Answer (score 1):

Goto Accessibility in Settings.

Tap on VoiceOver

Tap on Verbosity, toggle off "Speak Hints" option.

Comment: Thank you @devchaudhary, sounds promising but can't find this `Speech section` nor `Speak Hints`, did you mean `Spoken Content` maybe?

Comment: Hey @ssantos just edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you @devchaudhary, will give it a try as soon as I have access to the device. By the way, it turns out the issue only happens for English.